# VBA Conditional Formatting print format

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to list all the conditional formatting rules in a workbook and found the following code elsewhere. The subroutine lists out the name of the sheet, the formula applied and the range applied. I have two questions:

[image]

1. How do I add an extra column showing the how the format would look like?

[image]

2. Is there a way for me to change the rules in the Excel tab and flush them to the conditional formatting rule manager? How to preserve the order of which?

> ```
> Sub List_Conditional_Formatting_Rules()
>
> ' Print all conditional formatting rules in the all worksheets
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
>     Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCF As Worksheet, NR As Long
>     Dim CFrule As FormatCondition, Rng As range
>
>     On Error Resume Next
>
>     Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "CF Rules"   'add sheet
>     Set wsCF = Sheets("CF Rules")
>     wsCF.range("A1:C1").Value = [{"Sheet","Formula","Range"}]
>
>     NR = 2      'define starting row
>
>     For Each ws In Worksheets
>      If ws.Name <> "CF Rules" Then
>         Set Rng = ws.Cells
>
>         For Each CFrule In Rng.FormatConditions
>             wsCF.range("A" & NR).Value = ws.Name                    ' rule names
>             wsCF.range("B" & NR).Value = "'" & CFrule.Formula1      ' formula names
>             wsCF.range("C" & NR).Value = CFrule.AppliesTo.Address   ' applied area
>
>             ' want to add a column to show how the format actually looks like
>
>             NR = NR + 1
>         Next CFrule
>     End If
>
>     Next ws
>
>     wsCF.Columns.AutoFit
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     MsgBox ("All conditional formatting rules are printed.")
>
> End Sub
> ```

Please let me know if there are any documents that I could read to understand this better. Thanks!

Comment: See the [`FormatCondition` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition), especially its [`Interior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.interior), [`Borders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.borders), and [`Font`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.font) properties. From your screenshot, it looks like you're just (or mostly just) modifying the `Interior`.

Comment: So make the `Interior` of `wsCF.Range("D" & NR")` the same as `CFrule.Interior` by setting the properties, e.g. `Color`, equal to one another

Comment: Thanks for the note! I actually also have font color/boldness but I assume these properties are just the same as range right?

Comment: Right, you'd use the same approach - although the conditional format object model doesn't support all the `Interior`, `Borders` and `Font` properties that the `Range` would.

Comment: Alright, I will try to see what it offers :)